# filter list <object> with list<string> and look for a match in c#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list & List

I want to fetch the list of Car from the dbCars object with condition the the 
Name, Title,Comment properties contains any of the value in target_terms array [ Please note I am not trying to find array contains object Property , but i am trying the reverse] & assign a Rank on the fly to the result

I tried the below code [ which will check array contains any of the properties ]

```
 List<Car> dbCars;//Values from Db 
 List<string> target_terms=new List<string> {"diesel","mechanic"};
var ranked_result = (from carItem in dbContext.Cars                  
                     select new
                     {
                         carItem,
                         Rank =   target_terms.Contains(carItem.Title) ? 1 :
                                  target_terms.Contains(carItem.Name) ? 2 :                               
                                  target_terms.Contains(carItem.Comment) ? 3 :
                                 0
                     }).OrderBy(i => i.Rank);
 //exclude results with no match (rank=0 ) and get a Distinct set  of images
List<Car> _searchResult = (from item in ranked_result
                             where item.Rank != 0
                             select item.carItem).Distinct().ToList();
```

How can i write the same code to do the reverse ie to check the Car properties contain any of the words in target_terms

Example if i am searching for diesel and if i have 2 cars with Name "Swift Diesel car" "Alto Diesel car" it should return the 2 results 
ie My Properties Title or Name or Comment contains the word "diesel"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this,

```
var _searchResult = dbCars.Cars.Where(carItem => target_terms.Any(x => carItem.Title.Contains(x) ||
                                                                       carItem.Name.Contains(x) ||
                                                                       carItem.Comment.Contains(x)));
```

EDIT:

```
var _searchResult = dbCars.Cars.Where(carItem => target_terms.Any(x => carItem.Title.Contains(x) ||
                                                                       carItem.Name.Contains(x) ||
                                                                       carItem.Comment.Contains(x)))
                               .Select(carItem => new
                               {
                                   carItem,
                                   Rank = target_terms.Any(x => carItem.Title.Contains(x)) ? 1 :
                                          target_terms.Any(x => carItem.Name.Contains(x)) ? 2 :
                                          target_terms.Any(x => carItem.Comment.Contains(x)) ? 3 : 0
                               })
                               .OrderBy(carItem => carItem.Rank);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Can i add Rank as well with help of this querry

Comment: This idea of assigning of Rank is working but i am getting error while converting the List back 
Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.//exclude results with no match (rank=0 ) and get a Distinct set  of images
final_result = (from item in _searchResult 
   where item.Rank != 0
   select item.carItem).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: That exception is soled.. No wthe problem is Title, Name, Coment can be NUll. So execution gives null reference exception. Can we handle that inside this target_terms.Any(x => carItem.Title.Contains(x)

Comment: Yes it can be handled, like `target_terms.Any(x => (carItem.Title != null && carItem.Title.Contains(x))...`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find cars which have any word from target_terms in title, name or comment, use `.Where` query:

```
var result = dbContext.Cars.Where(c => 
    target_terms.Any(t => 
         c.Title.Contains(t)  ||
         c.Name.Contains(t))  ||
         c.Comment.Contains(t)));
```

Don't forget that the `.Contains` is case-sensitive;

If you need to match only a particular word, it's very similiar:

```
var match_word = "diesel";
var result = dbContext.Cars.Where(c => 
    c.Title.Contains(match_word)  ||
    c.Name.Contains(match_word))  ||
    c.Comment.Contains(match_word)));
```

In this case, it's unclear how this word be related to your target_terms list.

**Edit:** Fixed the queries checking for inclusion, not equality.

Comment: in your queries you are looking for the exact match for the target term. In OP's question the keyword might only be a part of the column value.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen, you are right, I've fixed the query.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried but this should do it:

```
var filteredCars = dbContext.Cars.Where(c => 
    target_terms.Any(tt => c.Title.Contains(tt)) ||
    target_terms.Any(tt => c.Name.Contains(tt)) ||
    target_terms.Any(tt => c.Comment.Contains(tt)));
```

Since being true for one of them is enough here, you don't have to worry about selecting distinct values.