# Filter Object List with string array list C# lambda expression

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda

I had tried a similar SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159218/filter-list-object-with-liststring-and-look-for-a-match-in-c-sharp) which not worked and might be missing something in my case.

Background:

I'm trying to pull a list of Trade Instruments from an external API ( around 8k records ) from which I need around 10 only. So trying to filter it as below , but the filter results are 0 .

Model:

```
public class Trade
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Scrip { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }            
}
```

Filtering:

```
List<Trade> trades;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Utils/trades.json")))
{
    trades = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Trade>>(sr.ReadToEnd());
}

List<Instrument> instruments = GetInstruments(Exchange: "NY");// count 8k
var result = instruments.Where(x => trades.Any(n => x.Name.Contains(n.Scrip))); //count 0
```

Also, tried to fetch the Scrip names from the trades list as string array and used for filtering which also didn't work.

Please advise and thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the debugger say? nail it down on one occurrence of `trades.Any(n => x.Name.Contains(n.Scrip))`, prove that it will be true for at least one entry in the actual data. Is it something basic, like a case mismatch (string comparisons are case sensitive by default)?

Comment: @dlatikay debugger not giving me much hints on this

Comment: make it! you're its boss :)

Comment: Are you certain that there is an `instrument` whose `Name` contains one the `Script` text of one of the items in `trades`?

Comment: @dlatikay . you are right :) , it says "unknown identifier" on hovering Name and Scrip

Comment: @RufusL Yes , I had crosschecked it . Its a kinda subset and super set with only few additional properties

Comment: And you sure the casing is exactly the same as well? Maybe you should try using a standard `foreach` loop instead of linq so you can set a conditional breakpoint inside the loop. The code looks ok, but without actual sample data there's only so much we can do.

Comment: @RufusL , Initially I tried with foreach loop then tried to linq predicates since it looked clumsy and slow. Does casting is important here as we are having different objects ?

Comment: I'd suggest saving the data you're being sent (unfiltered) locally - it'll then be much easier to see why it isn't working and repeat the test to get the code right.  Break out your Linq into multiple lines to see what you're getting at each stage, so you can identify what's going wrong.

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to wrt casting, but the code looks ok. Did the `foreach` loop work? If so, show that as well. If not, you might consider pre-filtering `trades` to only contain the `Scrip` value that you know is contained in the `Name` property of one of the items in `instruments`, and then step through the code.

Comment: @RufusL thanks for the thoughts.  foreach I just tried to iterate through the trades and equate a string . Can you tell how can I use Scrips ( multiple, looping again?)

Comment: @PhilS , thanks . I tried first assigning locally . Can you help me splitting the lambda expression so that it would be easier to debug.

Comment: @RufusL  foreach(var instrument in instruments)
                    {
                        foreach(var trade in Trades)
                        {
                            if( instrument.Name == trade.Scrip)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Match"+ trade.Scrip);
                            }
                        }
                    } this is working but don't know why the lambda expression is not

Comment: @RufusL , oh my .. I changed Contains to Equals and its working...

Comment: Can you please share the two strings where `Equals` returns true but `Contains` returns false? That doesn't make sense to me. But I'm glad it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for the help , was a silly mistake

changed Contains to Equals and its working as expected.

```
instruments.Where(x => trades.Any(n => x.Name.Equals(n.Scrip)));
```